# compile success build success but exe cannot run in vc++?

Tags: visual-c++

I wanna display image in vc++ using opencv. My program success to compile and build, but nothing display. How can like that?

Comment: You've probably done something wrong. That is the best I can say without seeing any code...

Comment: are you building a console program and not providing a pause?

Comment: Did you try stepping through it in a debugger? Does your code contain any error checking?